# Get all Fiware-ServicePath for a specific Fiware-Service

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I need to know all the available `Fiware-ServicePath` for a specific `Fiware-Service`.

For example: I have the following:

`Fiware-Service`: `MyCompany`

`Fiware-ServicePath`: `/app1`

`Fiware-ServicePath`: `/app2`

`Fiware-ServicePath`: `/app3`

What I want is a service that retrieves something like these:

```
{
    - {
        Service: "/app1"
      },
    - {
        Service: "/app2"
      },
    - {
        Service: "/app3"
      }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: To which FIWARE GEri does your question refer, please? Thanks!

Comment: @fgalan I omitted to say that I'm talking about Orion CB. My apologies.

Comment: No problem ;) Question edited to add "fiware-orion" label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orion Context Broker API doesn't allow to get a list of service paths (at least in the current version, i.e. Orion 1.7.0). As a workaround, you can get the list if you have access to the DB, for example running this query:

```
> db.entities.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$_id.servicePath"}}])
```

A possibility would be to wrap the above query with a REST service (using ligthweight frameworks such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in Python) and offer the information in a format as the one you suggest. It shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't figured out that!

Comment: I'm interested into get fiware-servicepath via API. Did you implement this feature? Thanks